# ExecutorService and List<Future<Callable>> with ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an ExecutorService that returns a List defined as `List<Callable> callables=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Callable>());`

I made it a synchronizedList when I first had the issue because I thought it would be thread safe, but the issue persists.

The problem I'm having is that the following Code is throwing a ConcurrentModificationException at `Future<Object> next = i.next();` below. Its worth noting that it makes it partially through the List before bombing out.

```
          ExecutorWorker snapshotExecutorWorker=new ExecutorWorker(this); 
      Iterator<Future<Object>> i= futures.iterator();
      while(i.hasNext()){
        Future<Object> next = i.next();//List<Callable>
        try {
            Object get = next.get();
            Class<? extends Object> aClass = get.getClass();
            System.out.println("Class= "+aClass);
         List<Callable> l=   (List)get;
         System.out.println("L.size= "+l.size());
       for(int a=0;a<l.size();a++){                 
        snapshotExecutorWorker.addTask(l.get(a));
       }

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

      }
```

ExecutorWorker is basically a SwingWorker that monitors the status of an ExecutorCompletionService.

```
public class ExecutorWorker extends SwingWorker<List<Future>, Object>   implements ExecutorInterface {

List<Future> results = new ArrayList();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
ExecutorCompletionService<Object> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
List<Future<Object>> jobs = new ArrayList();
ProgressMonitor progressMonitor;
boolean isExecuting = true;
Monitor monitor;

public ExecutorWorker(Monitor f) {
    monitor = f;

}

public void addMonitor(Monitor f) {
    monitor = f;
}

/**
 *This method adds Callables to the Executor.
 * @param r
 * @return 
 */
@Override
public Future<?> addTask(Callable r) {
    Future futureValue = ecs.submit(r);
    monitor.addFuture(futureValue);
    System.out.println("Callable added in [ExecutorWorker]");
    jobs.add(futureValue);
    monitor.tasksAdded(true);
    return futureValue;
}

/**
 *This method returns a List containing the Future results. Use Future.get() to retrieve.
 * @return
 */
public List<Future> getResults() {
    return results;
}

@Override
protected void done() {

}

@Override
protected List<Future> doInBackground() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
//        System.out.println("Executor: In Do In BackGround");
//        System.out.println("Jobs.size= " + jobs.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < this.jobs.size(); i++) {
        Future<Object> take = ecs.take();
        results.add(take);
        monitor.tasksCompleted(true);
        int v = (int) ((monitor.getCompletedTasks() /          this.monitor.getTotalTasks()) * 100);
        this.setProgress(v);
        String message = String.format("Processing " + (i + 1) + " of " +      jobs.size() + " Jobs. %d%%.\n", v);
        System.out.println("Message= " + message);
        progressMonitor.setNote(message);


    }

    return results;

}

public void setProgressMonitor(ProgressMonitor progressMonitor) {
    this.progressMonitor = progressMonitor;
}
}
```

Comment: No time to get into it right now but where do you get the futures collection from that you iterate over? Because it seems like you are changing that collection while you're trying to iterate over it which... welll... you can't do.

Comment: Your first block of code appears to have nothing to do with your second block of code.  I suspect the first block might be `addFuture` method of the `Monitor` class, but I'd rather not try to answer based on that much speculation.  Please show the method and class to which the first block of code belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Collections.synchronizedList() returns list with only methods synchronized, it not updates iterator, so ConcurrentModificationException is still possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify a list while iterating it, the iterators are invalidated and will throw ConcurrentModificationException the next time you use them (probably. Read about the "fail fast property of iterators" for the gory details).

All that making it a synchronizedList does is wraps each call to a method of the list in a synchronized block. You don't need to have multiple threads to get a ConcurrentModificationException, you just need to do something that breaks the iterator.

I believe in your specific example the issue is that addTask is causing the list that you are iterating to be modified.

This question illustrates the use of Iterator::remove(), which allows some modification of some sorts of collections while iterating them, though this is somewhat tangential to your actual question:
[Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing)

Comment: Do you think switching to a for loop would solve the issue?

Comment: It's got nothing to do with what sort of loop you're using.

Comment: Whoops, seems "enter" sends messages :P.

The problem is that an Iterator becomes invalid if the collection it is iterating over is modified. When you try and use an Iterator that has been invalidated in this way, it throws ConcurrentModificationException.

To fix your program, you need to make it stop modifying the list while in the process of iterating it. One approach might be to batch the modifications you want to do, and then apply them all at once after the loop. (have a "things to add" list which your loop fills, and then you add all of those things to the real list after the loop. say)